# To print console output to text file Java?

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter, file-writing, console-output

I'm trying to send the output of my program to a text file called results.txt . Here's my attempt

```
public void writeFile(){
        try{    
            PrintStream r = new PrintStream(new File("Results.txt"));
            PrintStream console = System.out;

            System.setOut(r);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot write to file");
        }
```

But everytime I run the code and open the file the file is blank. This is what i want to output:

```
public void characterCount (){
       int l = all.length();
       int c,i;
       char ch,cs;
       for (cs = 'a';cs <='z';cs++){
           c = 0;
           for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
               ch = all.charAt(i);
               if (cs == ch){
                   c++;
               }

           }
           if (c!=0){
//THIS LINE IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO PRINT
                System.out.println("The character"+ " "+ cs + " "+ "appears --> "+" "+c+" "+ "times");
           }
       }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong that it keeps creating the file but not writing to it?
(Btw i do have a main method)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Results.txt");

writer.print("something something");
```

don't forget to add:

```
writer.close();
```

when you are done!

Comment: @Bublegum Princess You'll find it useful also to open your PrintStream with autoFlush=true.

Answer (score 1):

As you found, `System.out` IS-A `PrintStream` and you can create a `PrintStream`, passing it a `File` to have it write to that file. This is the beauty of polymorphism --- your code writes to a `PrintStream` and it doesn't matter what kind it is: console, file, even network connection, or zipped encypted network file.

So instead of messing with `System.setOut` (usually a bad idea, as it may have unintended side effects; do this only if you absolutely have to (e.g., in some tests)), just pass the `PrintStream` of your choice to your code:

```
public void characterCount (PrintStream writeTo) {
    // (your code goes here)
    writeTo.println("The character"+ " "+ cs + " "+ "appears --> "+" "+c+" "+ "times");
    // (rest of your code)
}
```

Then you call your method as you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new YourClass().characterCount(System.out);
    new YourClass().characterCount(new PrintStream(new File("Results.txt")));
}
```

(Note that I declared that `main` may throw a `FileNotFoundException`, as `new File("...")` can throw that. When that happens, the program will exit with an error message and stack trace. You could also handle it like you did before in `writeFile`.)

Answer (score 0):

JAVADOC: "A PrintStream adds functionality to another output stream, namely the ability to print representations of various data values conveniently."

PrintStream can be used to write to an OutputStream, not directly to a file. So you can use PrintStream to write to a FileOutputStream and then write to the file with that.

If you just want to simply write to a file though, you can use Cans answer easily!